# How might I create a new Electrum wallet programmatically?

Tags: wallet, api, json-rpc, electrum, bip32-hd-wallets

I want to create a new wallet using Electrum-apis. I have gone through the documentation given [here](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/protocol.html) but I haven't found any method to create a new wallet or an address.

Would someone guide me in this?

Comment: That's the Electrum server API. Electrum does not have an API. Wallet creation is client-side, as a result the Electrum API won't help you.

Comment: Ohh.. So if wallet creation is client side, is there any known api available that can help me create Electrum wallet in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about an electrum wallet. The electrum API will allow you to query address balances, and build transactions, for any address, regardless of how they were created.

Electrum itself does use a special key derivation scheme, but that does not affect the usability from an API point of view. If you are using electrum servers as a backend, you should be able to generate wallets using any BIP39 library in your language of choice, and simply querying with the resulting addresses.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new wallet run the following in your terminal:

```
electrum create
```

The above will output a short message of instruction, the path, and the seed to the screen.
You can read more about this command on its man page that can be accessed
via `electrum help create`.